# Bitmap is stretching and not tiling

Tags: c++, windows, image, mfc, bitmap

I'm trying to get a bitmap to tile something like this:

```
 ----  ----  ----
|    ||    ||    |
 ----  ----  ----
```

doing the following as an example:

```
CD2DBitmapBrush* m_pBitBrush;
m_pBitBrush = new CD2DBitmapBrush(GetRenderTarget(), _T("grass.bmp"));

POINT pt;
pt.x = 0;
pt.y = 0;
CRect rect = new CRect(pt, m_pBitBrush->GetBitmap()->GetSize());

pRenderTarget->FillRectangle(rect, m_pBitBrush);


for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    pt.x += 40; 
    rect = new CRect(pt, m_pBitBrush->GetBitmap()->GetSize()); 
    pRenderTarget->FillRectangle(rect, m_pBitBrush);
}
```

When I do that, the bitmap displays correctly once, but every instance after that is "stretched" (i.e. the last column of pixels is repeated, but not the rest of the image).

If I change x, the right-most column is repeated. If I change y, the bottom row is repeated. And if i change both x and y (going diagonally), the corner pixel fills the rectangle.

```
x:
 ----  -----------
|    |||||||||||||
 ----  -----------

y:             x and y:
 ----                  *----*
|    |                 |    |
 ----                  *----*
 ----                        ******
 ----                        ******
 ----                        ******
```

Also, I have tried changing the image that the brush uses after it is called the first time, and nothing displays after the original.

```
CRect rect = new CRect(pt, m_pBitBrush->GetBitmap()->GetSize());
pRenderTarget->FillRectangle(rect, m_pBitBrush); 

CD2DBitmap* bit = new CD2DBitmap(GetRenderTarget()/*pRenderTarget*/, _T("stone.bmp"));  
m_pBitBrush->SetBitmap(bit);
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    pt.x += 40;
    rect = new CRect(pt, m_pBitBrush->GetBitmap()->GetSize()); 
    pRenderTarget->FillRectangle(rect, m_pBitBrush);
}
```

Surely, I am doing something wrong here since I am new, but I cannot seem to get this to work. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: +1 even just for the nice ASCII diagrams.

Comment: Thought it might be confusing without them. Hope it helps clarify what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `SetExtendModeX(D2D1_EXTEND_MODE mode)` and/or `SetExtendModeY(D2D1_EXTEND_MODE mode)` on your `CD2DBitmapBrush`. The default seems to be `D2D1_EXTEND_MODE.D2D1_EXTEND_MODE_CLAMP`, which causes the stretching. You want `D2D1_EXTEND_MODE.D2D1_EXTEND_MODE_WRAP`.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368100(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your help so far! This worked great for the initial tile/ brush, however, if i want to change the image that is being used for the brush, nothing displays after the initial rectangle has been filled. Do you have any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: Note: Re-creating the brush like `m_pBitBrush = new CD2DBitmapBrush(pRenderTarget, _T("stone.bmp"));` also replaces the fill of the original one.

Comment: I don't know what would be causing it, but it would make a degree of sense for each brush to be limited to one image.

Comment: So, creating a separate brush does indeed work, but this is slightly inconvenient if new tile types are created. Should I ask a separate question on how I might achieve this?